# Update to SQL View fails from Access with Linked Table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table that I created a view from. The view really doesn't change anything, except the order of the columns and one column is `converted` to a `varchar` from an `int`.

The view is set up as a linked table in Access 2013. Everything pulls in just fine. When I pull up a form in Access to edit rows in the view I get the problem.

I attempt to update the column `OSP_PERCENT_COMPLETE` with NA. The end users want this field to not be only an `int`. I updated the view so that it pulls the column like this:

```
convert(varchar(10),OSP_PERCENT_COMPLETE) OSP_PERCENT_COMPLETE
```

So it keeps the same name but is now a `varchar` field. Then when I go to update that field in the form I get this error message

> ODBC--update on a linked table 'PMDBII' failed
>   Access [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Update or Insert of view or function '' failed because it contains a derived or constant field. (#4406)

I can check the field in the PMDBII linked table and it shows it as a `short text` field with a length of 10.

One thing I should mention, most of this was set up by a coworker who is no longer with the company and I'm not as versed in Access as he was.

So why do I get the error?

Comment: You get the error because a 'view' does not change the fact that the underlying field is still an 'int'

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn So the base table field needs to be a `varchar` not just the view? That is something I should have known. Put that as an answer and I'll close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because a 'view' does not change the fact that the underlying field is still an 'int'. If you use a form, possibly you could include code on a 'before change' event that translates NA to null, but that could be a bad idea.

Comment: Makes me feel pretty dumb for not realizing that to begin with. Thanks